# AAR libs no longer created in the output folder with Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, gradle, aar, android-studio-3.0, android-gradle-3.0

I have some lib modules in my Android project. Before updating Android Studio to the new 3.0 version and so the Gradle plugin to the 3.0.0 one, I was able to find the AAR file of my libs into the builder/output folder after building the project.

It seems that the AAR libs are no longer produced in this new version.

Is there any alternative way to get them again?

Comment: `gradle [module_name]:build` or `./gradlew [module_name]:build` in terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, where I am building with Jenkins and I want to have both the apk and aar in my artifacts I could achieve this by adding :[module_name]:bundleRelease to the targets.

So if your module name is test:

```
:app:assembleRelease :test:bundleRelease
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: since gradle 3.2.0, you need to use **bundleReleaseAar** instead of **bundleRelease**, as noted also in [why android gradle maven publish artifact bundleRelease not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51433769/why-android-gradle-maven-publish-artifact-bundlerelease-not-found/51869825#51869825)