# why android gradle maven publish artifact bundleRelease not found

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

When i sync project, android studio warn `could not get unknown property 'bundleRelease' for object of type org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publication.DefaultMavenPublication.`

I add `project.afterEvaluate{//block}`,but it doesn't work. What should i do to set the `artifact`

Answer (score 32):

Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.x (at least -alpha releases at the time of writing this answer) has breaking change, task `bundleRelease` was renamed to `bundleReleaseAar`

So the solution is to use: `bundleReleaseAar` instead of `bundleRelease`.

Note: "release" in the task name is buildType/flavor combination, thus it might be different in your setup.

---

Generic answer: `bundleRelease` is a task, to find its new name you can run `./gradlew tasks --all`

Comment: This also applies to the newly stable Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.0.

Comment: Now at `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0` the same issue for `artifact bundleReleaseAar`, what to use instead of `bundleReleaseAar`?

Comment: @NickUnuchek It seems we must wrap the whole ```publishing {...}``` block into ```project.afterEvaluate { publishing { ... } }```, then it works.

Answer (score 22):

So the answer from [Artem Zunnatullin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1562633/artem-zinnatullin) is correct. Just one addition, the `project.afterEvaluate{//block}` is necessary to make it work. This information can be overlooked very easily.

Complete example:

```groovy
project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            mavenDebugAAR(MavenPublication) {
                artifact bundleDebugAar

                pom.withXml {
                    def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                    configurations.api.allDependencies.each { ModuleDependency dp ->
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dp.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dp.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dp.version)

                        if (dp.excludeRules.size() > 0) {
                            def exclusions = dependencyNode.appendNode('exclusions')
                            dp.excludeRules.each { ExcludeRule ex ->
                                def exclusion = exclusions.appendNode('exclusion')
                                exclusion.appendNode('groupId', ex.group)
                                exclusion.appendNode('artifactId', ex.module)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            mavenReleaseAAR(MavenPublication) {
                artifact bundleReleaseAar

                pom.withXml {
                    def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                    configurations.api.allDependencies.each { ModuleDependency dp ->
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dp.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dp.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dp.version)

                        if (dp.excludeRules.size() > 0) {
                            def exclusions = dependencyNode.appendNode('exclusions')
                            dp.excludeRules.each { ExcludeRule ex ->
                                def exclusion = exclusions.appendNode('exclusion')
                                exclusion.appendNode('groupId', ex.group)
                                exclusion.appendNode('artifactId', ex.module)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        repositories {

            maven {
                name 'nexusSnapshot'
                credentials {
                    username '<User with deployment rights>'
                    password '<User password>'
                }
                url '<URL to nexus>'
            }

            maven {
                name 'nexusRelease'
                credentials {
                    username '<User with deployment rights>'
                    password '<User password>'
                }
                url '<URL to nexus>'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this with a complete example! It really saved my day!